# Image positioning using CSS. (a little jQuery involved)

Tags: jquery, css, position, toggle

Having a bit of CSS problem here. First off, my HTML code:

```
<p>
<span id="tripTitle">Created Trips</span>&nbsp;
<span class="expandicon" style="display:none;"><span class="flip"><img class="expand" src="http://i228.photobucket.com/albums/ee190/micmofo/expand1.png" /></span></span>
<span class="shrinkicon"><span class="flip"><img class="shrink" src="http://i228.photobucket.com/albums/ee190/micmofo/shrink1.png" /></span></span>
</p>
```

My jQuery code toggles the images.

```
$(function(){
    $('span.expandicon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggle().next('span.shrinkicon').toggle();    
    });
    $('span.shrinkicon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggle().prev('span.expandicon').toggle();        
    });
})
```

And lastly, my CSS:

```
.expand, .shrink { 
    position: absolute;
    right:1px;
}
```

I want the image to go to the rightmost part of the page but using the current CSS I have, the "shrink" icon stays and so the "expand" icon isn't seen at all. I'm fairly new with CSS so all I know is by removing the styling, it actually works. So most probably, the problem is with the CSS.

I've provided a jsfiddle for those willing to help. http://jsfiddle.net/vfpM5/

Thanks, guys.

Comment: This might be a dumb comment, but when I looked at your link and moved the icon out from under the "Result" span on JSFiddle it seemed to toggle correctly.  See http://jsfiddle.net/CqdRP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS to below then work...

```
.expandicon, .shrinkicon{ 
    position: absolute;
    right:1px;
}
```

also , I added `top:50px;` to the css so it would be blocked by the jsfiddle `result` thing.

Comment: This absolutely worked! How come? This gave me a headache to be honest. Thanks, Quincy.

Comment: Actually I also cant tell why your solution didn't work. But when I tried to unify the elements and it magically worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `float: right`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfpM5/1/

Comment: Tried your jsfiddle but after clicking it displays both buttons side by side.